# It keeps saying I am missing a semi colon in my css when doing npm run production

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass

**Edit**

I am using Laravel with Vue and currently I am using vue route lazy loading.  All things runs fine when I compile with npm dev.  However when I did npm production it says I have a CSS missed semicolon error.  This can be resolve by NOT lazy loading all the vue route.

My question is why does this "missed semicolon" occurs when only I am using lazy loading.

I have tried lazy loading part of my route and sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.

Much appreciated if anyone has encountered this issue and know how to resolve it.

Webpack.mix

```
mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
.sass("resources/sass/app.scss", "public/css")
.sass("resources/sass/system.scss", "public/css");

.barbelrc
{
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```

route.js

Normal (without lazy load)

```
import appPanel from "./components/application/Base.vue";
```

Lazy loading

```
let appPanel = () => import("./components/application/Base.vue");
```

> CssSyntaxError: C:\css\app.css:10972:13: Missed semicolon

```
Added the SCSS file
// Variables
@import "variables";

// Bootstrap
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~toastr/toastr.scss";

html,
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    @media (max-width: 991px) {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
}
.cursor-pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.line-break {
    white-space: pre-line;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

.shadow {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) !important;
}

.table {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.border-1 {
    border: 2px solid;
}
.border-2 {
    border: 4px solid;
}
.border-3 {
    border: 6px solid;
}
.border-4 {
    border: 8px solid;
}
.border-5 {
    border: 10px solid;
}

.rounded-top-2 {
    border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
}
.icon_wrapper {
    max-width: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .form-control {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .mobile-no-border {
        border: none !important;
    }
    .mobile-no-px {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the `app.scss` file? Maybe there can be some typo which is causing this issue...

Comment: This question was asked multiple times in the past. Please provide your css file, along with the specified error location

Comment: Dynamic import doesn't work ref https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/releases/tag/v4.0.0 `If your project heavily uses JavaScript dynamic imports, you may need to hold off until the release of webpack 5 early next year. There are known compile issues related to this that we cannot fix until then. Once webpack 5 is out, Mix will be updated shortly after. If you're unfamiliar with dynamic imports, then this very likely won't affect your project.`

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I get the same error in Less when I import an unused file. In your example you import `variables.scss` but you don't seem to use anything from that file.

Try deleting `@import "variables";`, the problem is probably in that file or some other file that you import.

When I got the same error it was because my `animations.scss` had a class that used an animation like this:

```
.blink {
  animation: 1s blink infinite;
}
```

I simply changed the order of the animation properties to this and now it builds without errors.

```
.blink {
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
}
```

I can't explain why this has anything to do with "Missed semicolon" but hopefully it helps someone out there.

Comment: Coming from NextJs, webpack gave me the same error. NextJs was using webpack5 and it didn't show which line was causing the error, switching to webpack4 (just add `webpack5: false` in `next.config.js` file), did show where was the problem. Also in my case, it was the animation property that caused the error. I fixed it by splitting it into its sub-properties like `animation-name` or `animation-timing-function` and ... .Hope it helps someone out there.

Comment: Sorry, this is bonkers, but after HOURS of trying to fix this issue, I found an animation that was out of order... thanks but also what a weird bug.